# Append in file a linux command

Tags: linux

When doing

```
echo "some stuff" >> file.txt
```

I can append to my file `some stuff`
But when trying to do

```
echo ls >> file.txt
```

I append `ls` instead of listing all my items in the current path. How can I fix this? Sorry I'm new to linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just redirect the ls output

```
ls >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ls >> file.txt
```

This is interpreted as `echo` the term `ls` to `file.txt`. This isn't what you want.

`>>` redirects the output of a command, which can be `ls`.

So you could do:

```
ls >> file.txt
```